# Google Sheets: Link Add-on Help item with function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm publishing and Add-on for Google Sheets.
This is the function that creates the menu under the Add-ons tab:

```
function onOpen(e) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
  .createAddonMenu()
  .addItem('Start', 'showSidebar')
  .addToUi();
}
```

It is working OK and it also creates a Help menu item.

Now, I have a help function but how do I link it to this item?

Answer (score 0):

For this you can simply add the help function code in a function named `"showSidebar"` as it mentions in this [page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/menu#addItem(String,String)).

If this not what you wanted to implement, add it in comments or edit your question.